# Creating movie from collection of layers with open source software?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, video

I have a collection of raster layers portraying a certain spatial phenomenon at successive time steps. I would like to create a video from these layers, with the same colour scheme applied on each time step.

The output can either be a video file or something else like an animated GIF.

I am not interested in commercial software. I wish to accomplish this task with open source software.

Many of the tasks in this process are spatial related:

- reading/processing a large number of raster files;
- applying a single cloropleth to multiple rasters;
- applying a same legend to multiple rasters;
- automatic production of maps as images.

Comment: I think this question might be better suited to the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question would be immediately rejected at SoftRecs since it is asking for a method, not for a particular software.

Comment: Blender might be a possible choice https://www.blender.org/features/

Comment: If you are after a method then I think you need to work on each of its steps a question at a time. I doubt that you are stuck on reading raster files so is it the second step or how to turn a series of rendered images into video/animation, or something else?

Comment: Blender does not seem able to [read in raster files](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Outdated/Resources/File_Formats). But it could help with a final step of creating a video from multiple maps.